# Getting error when using Decodable for JSON - Swift

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I am trying to use Decodable but I get this error and can't figure out why: **Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Data'**

Here's my code:

```
struct JSONResponse : Decodable {
var places :[Place]
}

struct Place : Decodable {

    var name :String
    var latitude :Double
    var longitude :Double
}

let json = """

{
     "places":[
            {
                "name" : "San Diego",
                "latitude" : 32.71,
                "longitude" : -117.16
            },
            {
                "name" : "Los Angeles",
                "latitude" : 34.05,
                "longitude" : -118.24
            }
            ]
}

"""

let placesResponse = try! 
JSONDecoder().decode(JSONResponse.self, from: json)
print(placesResponse.places)
```

Comment: It's all in the error message and Xcode pointed out on what line the error was, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to convert your `String` into the `Data` type you need to call `.data` and set the `String` instance property by setting the `using` parameter like this:

```
""".data(using: .utf8)!  // added code

let placesResponse = try! JSONDecoder().decode(JSONResponse.self, from: json)
print(placesResponse.places)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `.decode` function take argument of `Data` not `String` therefore
just convert the `JSON` to `Data`

```
JSONDecoder().decode(JSONResponse.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
```